# How to add if statement inside loop

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

On a wordress site I'm building, for the first time, I'm trying to add custom loops.

```
<?php 
$custom_loop = new WP_Query('showposts=5&category_name=Featured&orderby=rand');
if ( $custom_loop->have_posts() ) :
echo '<ul>';
while ( $custom_loop->have_posts() ):     
    $custom_loop->the_post();
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a>
    </li>';
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
echo '</ul>';
endif;
?>
```

How do I correctly add this line `if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail();}` inbetween the `<li></li>` tags?

I've tried just placing it in, but it shows up like normal text on the site.

Comment: Yes, which is at the start and end of the loop?

Comment: Oooh. I didn't look close enough. You simply tried to put it inside an echo statement, which will obviously not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to put `the_post_thumbnail()` value between li tag, use below code instead of your `echo '<li>.....';`

```
echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a>';
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
  the_post_thumbnail();
}
echo '</li>';
```

Comment: Perfect, I will accept this answer in 6 minutes haha. Can you explain why I have to echo `</li>` ?

Comment: In first echo code you opened the <li> tag and at last you have to close it after checking thumbnail.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php 
  $custom_loop = new WP_Query('showposts=5&category_name=Featured&orderby=rand');
  if ($custom_loop->have_posts()) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ($custom_loop->have_posts()) {
      $custom_loop->the_post();
      $thumb = (has_post_thumbnail()) ? the_post_thumbnail() : '';
      printf('<li><a href="%s">%s</a>%s</li>', get_permalink(), get_the_title(), $thumb);
    }
    wp_reset_query();
    echo '</ul>';
  }
?>
```